# error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have been trying to run git push heroku master since yesterday. I have done searches and nothing has fix the issue. I'm following http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book. I just previously ran the heroku create command and now I have to push it. As you can see I get a error. Any help would be greatly appreciated so I can continue on with tutorial :)

```
lexi87$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 64, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
Writing objects: 100% (64/64), 26.00 KiB, done.
Total 64 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.0.3)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)
       Installing multi_json (1.5.0)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.11)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.11)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.4)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.1)
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.11)
       Installing mime-types (1.19)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.12)
       Installing mail (2.4.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.11)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.11)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.11)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
       Installing json (1.7.6)
       Installing rdoc (3.12)
       Installing thor (0.16.0)
       Installing railties (3.2.11)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (2.1.4)
       Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.5)
       Installing rails (3.2.11)
       Installing sass (3.2.5)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.5)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_ry8rc70jirtv/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_ry8rc70jirtv/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:boiling-waters-1006.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:boiling-waters-1006.git'
```

Answer (score 3):

Heroku does not support SQLite databases. The error is because the machine heroku provided does not have the necessary SQLite libraries installed

```
checking for sqlite3.h... no
```

You need to use Postgres. In your `Gemfile` add:

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby"
end
```

Comment: Tried and did not work. My gem file is at https://gist.github.com/4548427. Error I have is "exec request failed on channel 0
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Comment: @CorneliusWilson make sure `gem "sqlite3-ruby"` only appears under the `:development, :test` group and not anywhere else in the Gemfile. You may need to generate a new `Gemfile.lock` by issuing `bundle update`

Comment: It is there. I posted gemfile on gist

Comment: @CorneliusWilson post your `Gemfile.lock` to a gist please. I'll bet it still has `sqlite3-ruby`

Comment: @CorneliusWilson `bundle update` locally. This will generate a new `Gemfile.lock` and remove the `sqlite3-ruby` dependency.

Comment: I ran the bundle update and after successful installation I still get the same error, even after restarting Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to run this command rm -rf .bundle && bundle install && git add Gemfile.lock && git commit -m "Added Gemfile.lock"

Now it works perfect.